# docker toolbox, can connect to containers launched with kitematic but not with the cli?

Tags: macos, docker

I have docker toolbox 1.8.2c installed on my Mac running yosemite. If I launch hello-world-nginx from the docker hub in Kitematic, I can connect to its TCP port without an issue.

When trying to do the same thing from the CLI, I can't connect. Why?

Here is what I am running on the  docker CLI, which looks to me to be pretty standard:

```
docker run -d -i -t -P kitematic/hello-world-nginx /bin/sh
```

In the case above, `docker ps` shows that port 80 is mapped to 0.0.0.0:32769. So I try and connect on 192.168.99.100:32769 (that's my docker machine IP) and I can't connect.

I want to use the CLI so I can set the hostname/fqdn on the container, which it doesn't look like Kitematic supports. Here is another thing I tried, with the IP address of my docker machine in the args:

```
docker run -d -i -t -p 192.168.99.100:32769:80 -h nginx.example.com kitematic/hello-world-nginx /bin/sh
```

This doesn't work either.

In each case, the container starts successfully and I can `attach` to it with out an issue.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but in windows 10 pro witn the same image  kitematic/hello-world-nginx. Kitematic was open a wep page by default with Internet Explorer and the message was inmediatetly can't connect, later I tried with another web browers, chrome, and it worked. maybe if you try with another web browser, this problem can be solved.